# Use Duhamel principle to find inhomogenous solution to $u_t-u_{xx}=sin^2(x)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Question as it appeared in the book:
$$u_t-u_{xx}=sin^2(x) \quad 0<x<\pi, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=\frac{\pi x}{2}\quad 0<x<\pi$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0$$
The homogeneous solution of the above problem is given by
$$u_h(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n e^{-n^2t}cos(nx)$$
with $C_n=-2/n^2$ for odd n and $C_n=0$ otherwise. Use Duhamel principle to find the inhomogeneous solution.

Theory stated in book:
For: $$u_t-ku_{xx}=f(x,t) \quad 0<x<l, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=g(x)\quad 0<x<l$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(l,t)=0$$
Duhamel principle:
$$u(x,t)= S(t)g(x)-\int_0^tS(t-s)f(x,s)ds=u_h(x,t)+w(x,t) $$
$$u_h(x,t)+w(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_nX_n(x)e^{-kt\lambda_nt}+\int_0^t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n(s)X_n(x)e^{-kt\lambda_n(t-s)}$$
Where:
$$A_n=\frac{<X_n,g(x)>}{<X_n,X_n>}$$
$$B_n=\frac{<X_n,f(s)>}{<X_n,X_n>}$$
My attempt:
Taking n is odd,$\lambda_n=n^2$ and $k=1$
$$u(x,t)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-2}{n^2}e^{-n^2t}cos(nx) +\int_0^{t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(s)e^{-n^2(t-s)}cos(nx) $$
$$B_n(s)=\frac{<cos(nx),sin^2(x)>}{<cos(nx),cos(nx)>}$$
$$<cos(nx),cos(nx)>=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
as n is odd and n>0 and $cos(x)$ is repeating $cos(nx)=cos(x)$
$$<cos(nx),sin^2(x)>=\int_0^{\pi}cos(x)sin^2(x)dx=[\frac{sin^3(x)}{3}]_0^{\pi}=0-0=0$$
$$B_n=0$$
$$u(x,t)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-2}{n^2}e^{-n^2t}cos(nx) $$
I don't think this can be right as I can't see how you can get $u(x,0)=\frac{\pi x}{2}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.